fedora 9 install on sata internal SSD
Am Interested to know whether FC9 can be installed on internal sata SSD or it supports pata drives only?

Fedora does support external SATA drives however it remains to be seen whether your system can actually boot from them.
Fedora 9 is extremely outdated and insecure, and must not be used anywhere except in a Virtual Machine or isolated network. You could probably use something like RHEL7 with ELS instead if you need a really old kernel or software stack.

yes am going to use in isolated network . am trying to use since the system was stable with other rpms which dont have updated versions.  i am using an internal sata ssd 240gb. basically while installing its not showing the hdd in the installation page. kindly help.

Fedora 9 was released back in 2008.
It supports SATA drives.
It doesn't support hardware "RAID" modes, Intel RST or similar new technologies.
It should support AHCI but may not support newer SATA controllers but, if available, "IDE compatibility", "Native IDE" or similar modes should work.
Wheteher it works or not in an acceptable way depends mostly of the hardware's (motherboard's) age. Something a decade newer than the Fedora version you intend to install is likely too new to be doable.

Yes. First of all thank a lot for replying. I am messed. I tried installing fc38, installed working fine. But when going for fc9, it's not showing the ssd. Is there any way out to install fc9? Btw can i run the fc9 while am on fc38 like we do in windows? Kind of windows update. Pleas let me know. TIA.

I would love to post some screenshot but don't know how to. If possible let me know.

If a current Fedora release works and for some unfathomable reason you want to run an ancient release it's better to do it in a virtual machine.
